Fuzzy name matching with conditions
I want to do a fuzzy match between two dfs. The first df has a list of names with unique IDs and other data, e.g.:
    ID      Name         A  B
0   12445   John Smith   a  b
1   23455   Jack Smith   a  b
2   93854   David Brown  x  y
3   98736   Jason Smitdt a  b

df1 =  pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 12445, 1: 23455, 2: 93854, 3: 98736},
 'Name': {0: 'John Smith',
  1: 'Jack Smith',
  2: 'David Brown',
  3: 'Jason Smitdt'},
 'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'x', 3: 'a'},
 'B': {0: 'b', 1: 'b', 2: 'y', 3: 'b'}})

The other df has a list of name with not unique ids e.g.:
    ID      Name         A  B
0   12445   John Smith   a  b
1   12445   Johny Smith  a  b
2   23455   Jack Smith   a  b
3   93854   David Brown  x  y
4   98736   Jason Smitdt w  NaN
5   98736   Jesse Smith  w  NaN

df2 =  pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 12445, 1: 12445, 2: 23455, 3: 93854, 4: 98736, 5: 98736},
 'Name': {0: 'John Smith',
  1: 'Johny Smith',
  2: 'Jack Smith',
  3: 'David Brown',
  4: 'Jason Smitdt',
  5: 'Jesse Smith'},
 'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'x', 4: 'w', 5: 'w'},
 'B': {0: 'b', 1: 'b', 2: 'b', 3: 'y', 4: nan, 5: nan}})

I want match df1 against df2 and retrieve all the potential matches higher than let's say 40%. Additionally:

I need to discard the matches against the name with the same ID. E.g. the IDs 12445 from both dfs shouldn't produce a potential match.
I need to be able to play with ratio.
If it matched more than once to the names under same ID, need to retrieve only one result (highest ratio). E.g.John Smith ID 12445 from df1 shouldn't have more than one match displayed against ID 98736 of df2.

So at the end the result table should look sth like this:

If this request is too much or not well written, let me know.

"Something like this" is a little vague and misleading. If I follow your logic right, you should do this:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [12445, 23455, 93854, 98736],
    'Name': ['John Smith', 'Jack Smith', 'David Brown', 'Jason Smitdt'],
    'A': ['a', 'a', 'x', 'a'],
    'B': ['b', 'b', 'y', 'b']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [12445, 12445, 23455, 93854, 98736, 98736],
    'Name': ['John Smith', 'Johny Smith', 'Jack Smith', 'David Brown', 'Jason Smitdt', 'Jesse Smith'],
    'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'x', 'w', 'w'],
    'B': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'y', np.nan, np.nan]
})

def find_best_match(row, df2, threshold=40):
    matches = []
    for _, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row['ID'] != row2['ID']:
            ratio = fuzz.ratio(row['Name'], row2['Name'])
            if ratio > threshold:
                matches.append((row2['ID'], row2['Name'], row2['A'], row2['B'], ratio))
    
    if matches:
        matches.sort(key=lambda x: x[4], reverse=True)
        best_match = matches[0]
        return pd.Series([best_match[4], best_match[0], best_match[1], best_match[2], best_match[3]])
    return pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])

results = df1.apply(find_best_match, args=(df2, 50), axis=1)
results.columns = ['Ratio', 'Matched_ID', 'Matched_Name', 'Matched_A', 'Matched_B']

final_df = pd.concat([df1, results], axis=1)

final_df = final_df.dropna(subset=['Ratio'])

print(final_df)


which gives you
     ID          Name  A  B  Ratio  Matched_ID  Matched_Name Matched_A  \
0  12445    John Smith  a  b   73.0     98736.0  Jason Smitdt         w   
1  23455    Jack Smith  a  b   70.0     12445.0    John Smith         a   
3  98736  Jason Smitdt  a  b   73.0     12445.0    John Smith         a   

  Matched_B  
0       NaN  
1         b  
3         b  

Not the ration column. In you "something like this"-output, there are all 0.5 (50%), but you will not get that. fuzzywuzzy determines the ratio, not you.
